# How do I check if a method exists and returns some value or not in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a google drive api, where I am fetching a file object from the google drive api. <strike>Now</strike> that file may/may not have the downloadLink and the webContentLink depending on the user authenticating the file. <strike>Now</strike> I have these methods where

```
download_links[index][1] = i.webContentLink if i.responds_to? :webContentLink
```

<strike>Now</strike> it says responds_to is not defined for i. 
<strike>Now</strike> i is a remote object, so i cannot change its implementation and add method_missing or responds_to method. <strike>so</strike> how do i check if i.webContentLink is a valid method or not in that ith object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things, here.

First, `#responds_to?` indeed does not exist, anywhere :) The correct method name for what you want to use is `#respond_to?`.

Secondly, this is not a ruby method as you ask for it, but I mention it since you post your question with ruby on rails tag. ActiveSupport, from rails, implements a `#try` method to do that.

It will return the result of the method if it exists, or nil :

```
download_links[index][1] = i.try( :webContentLink )
```

Be sure not to abuse that, as it quickly leads to hard to understand code (at some point, you will want to learn about [NullObjects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object)).